# Simple question during a proof. Reducing a factorial...

Tags: analysis, factorial

So I'm reading over a proof-review and stuck on how they managed to convert:

$\limsup \displaystyle \frac{|n!|^\frac{1}{2}}{|(n+1)!^\frac{1}{2}|} = \limsup  \displaystyle\frac{1}{(n+1)^\frac{1}{2}}$

Simple factorial confusion...

Comment: What are the absolute values there for?  If it is just $\dfrac{n!}{(n+1)!}$, then that is a bizarre step, although true because both numbers are $0$.

Comment: $\frac{n!}{(n+1)!}=\frac1{n+1}$. Is there perhaps $1/2$ missing in the exponent somewhere?

Comment: Yes, there is a square root on the first portion. That was my mistake. 

The question was actually: Determine which of the following series converge and justify your answers. (a) Series: 1/square root of (n!)

I was just confused on the portion I posted above... simply how the factorials are reduced to such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just remember that square roots (and taking powers in general) respect multiplication multiplicatively: $\sqrt{ab}=\sqrt{a}\sqrt{b}$, provided these are well defined. So in your problem:

$\begin{align} \frac{\sqrt{n!}}{\sqrt{(n+1)!}}
 &= \frac{\sqrt{n\cdot(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}}{\sqrt{(n+1)\cdot n\cdot\ldots\cdot 1}}
 = \frac{\sqrt{n}\cdot\sqrt{n-1}\cdot\ldots\cdot \sqrt{1}}{\sqrt{n+1}\cdot \sqrt{n}\cdot\ldots\cdot \sqrt{1}}
 =\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}.
\end{align}$